# Python: RegEx, all occurrence of text "NN.N percent" to "NN.N%"

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a big string which has texts like "NN.N percent" or "N.NN percent" or ".NN percent" etc [max 2 significant digits], which i want to convert to  "NN.N%" in python.

How can i leverage regex to achieve this.

Comment: What do you currently have? And what is the issue for it? Not gonna write it for you, but we can help you debug your issues.

Comment: What about 100.00 or 100.0?

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\d*\.\d{1,2})\spercent', r'\1%', s)`

Comment: @chrisz: Thanks for the template. This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @MattClark: Hi Matt. I understand what your're saying. I am pretty new to re, and needed a starting point. Will take care of it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered by @chrisz above in the comments.

```
re.sub(r'(\d*\.\d{1,2})\spercent', r'\1%', s)
```